# Understanding where an example of an invertible map came from

Tags: proof-explanation, linear-transformations

I am trying to understand a solution to the below problem.

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $F$ and $T,S: V \to V$ linear operators satisfying $T \circ S - S \circ T = S$. Show that if $F$ is a finite field, then $S$ can be invertible.

After struggling with this problem, I took a look at the solution which gives the following example. Let $F = (F_p)^p$ (the field of $p$-tuples of elements of $F_p$) with basis $e_0, e_1, \ldots, e_{p-1}$ (the standard basis) and $T$ and $S$ the linear maps
$$
T(e_j) = j e_j, \; S(e_j) = e_{j+1}).
$$
I was able to verify, by using the fact that $T \circ S$ and $S \circ T$ are linear, that $(T \circ S) - (S \circ T) = S$. The map is surjective since its image contains each of the $p$ standard basis vectors, so it's invertible.

I can work through the details and understand the mechanics of the solution, but I am struggling for how I could come up with a solution like this. Taking $V$ to be the set of $p$-tuples seems to be a natural, easy to work with choice, as is the standard basis. I cannot figure out why it is convenient to define $T$ to multiply $e_j$ by $j$ or $S$ to shift the index forward mod $p$.

Comment: Another puzzle: where does this solution use that $F$ is a finite field?

Comment: Your definition of $S$ needs some clarification - what is $S(e_{p-1})$? If this is meant to be the right-shift operator, so that $S(e_{p-1}) = 0$, then it's not going to be invertible.

Comment: @Prasiortle Sorry, I meant to say that the shift is mod $p$, so $S(e_{p-1}) = e_0$.

Comment: @Karl I'm actually not sure.

Comment: @ValorVaporeon I see. In that case, one answer is that shifts of this type (permuting the elements of a given basis) are some of the most basic examples of invertible linear maps on a finite-dimensional space, so in a sense they're one of the first things to try. It's then possible to let $T$ be represented by an arbitrary matrix, and find what constraints it must satisfy with this choice of $S$. It turns out that there must be a common difference of $1$ between successive elements on the diagonal of the matrix, and that the elements along each 'off-diagonal' must be equal.